# Cannot add Listeners

Tags: java, swing, listeners

I'm trying to put some Listeners in my code but I can't. For example I want to add a listener and when I write somenthing in the textfield area , then I choose the JRadioButton "From TextField" and after that I push the button "Do It" , I want to see the text that I wrote(in TextField)  on JTextArea. How is that possible?

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javafx.scene.Group;

    public class Layout {
    final static boolean shouldFill = true;
    final static boolean shouldWeightX = true;
    final static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;
    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        if (RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {
            pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);}

        JButton button;
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();

    if (shouldFill) {
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;}
    JTextField text = new JTextField( "Some Text");
    if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;}
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
        c.ipady = 50;
    pane.add(text, c);

    String names[] = { "Ferrari", "Koenigsegg", "Alfa Romeo" };
        JComboBox cb = new JComboBox( names );
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
        c.ipady = 50;
    pane.add(cb, c);

        Box box=Box.createVerticalBox();

    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("Water");
        JCheckBox checkbox2 = new JCheckBox("Fire");
        JCheckBox checkbox3 = new JCheckBox("Earth");

        c1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c1.weightx = 0.5;
        c1.ipady = 5;

        box.add(checkbox);
        box.add(checkbox2);
        box.add(checkbox3);

        pane.add(box,c1);

    JPanel container = new JPanel();    
    container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0,100,50);
    slider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,20));
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);  
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);  
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);  
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);  

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.ipady = 40;     
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(slider, c);

    JTextField text1 = new JTextField(" ");
    c.ipady = 80;     
    c.weighty = 2.0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE; 
    c.gridx = 0;      
    c.gridwidth = 3;   
    c.gridy = 2;       
    pane.add(text1, c);


        JRadioButton b1= new JRadioButton("From JTextField");
        JRadioButton b2= new JRadioButton("From JComboBox");
        JRadioButton b3= new JRadioButton("From JCheckboxes");
        JRadioButton b4= new JRadioButton("J Slider");

        b1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        b2.setForeground(Color.RED);
        b3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
         Box box1 = Box.createHorizontalBox();

      box1.add(b1);
      box1.add(b2);
      box1.add(b3);
      box1.add(b4);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 10;     
    c.weighty = 1.0; 
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE; 
    c.gridx = 0;      
    c.gridwidth = 3;   
    c.gridy =2; 

            pane.add(box1,c);

    button = new JButton("Do it");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.ipady =0;     
    c.weighty = 1.0;   
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; 
    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0); 
    c.gridx = 0;      
    c.gridwidth =3;   
    c.gridy = 2;       
    pane.add(button, c);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" ");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600,400);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });   
}

    }
```

Comment: Please 1) format your code for readability. Indention especially should be improved, since if your code is easier to read and understand, you're likely going to have more folks reading it and answering your question. 2) Let us know what problems you're having with your attempt to add listeners. You show no such attempt at adding listeners anywhere in the code above, so it's difficult to know what your trouble is.

Comment: How is the title related to the text? How is the text related to the code?

Comment: [How to use button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write action listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) - SO is not a replacement for tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html). The first example shows how to append text from a JTextField to a JTextArea. This example uses an ActionListener for the text field.

> then I choose the JRadioButton "From TextField" and after that I push the button "Do It" , I want to see the text that I wrote(in TextField) on JTextArea.

The concept will be similar except you add the ActionListener to you button. Then when it is invoked you check if the "From TextField" radio button is selected. If so, then you get the text from the text field and append it to the text area.